# Move a row from one gridview to another

Tags: vb.net, gridview, row, transfer

I'm not sure how to go about this. Currently, in the **first gridview**, is a list of groups a member has access to. The **second gridview** is bound to a table that contains a list of every type of group and has an Add button which adds it to the first gridview and updates a table adding that group to a member.

This is what I am trying to do:

When the Add button (in the second gridview) for a row is clicked, it will be added to the first one (like it currently does), but I would also like it to disappear from the second gridview. So basically, a group should only be visible in either the first gridview or the second, not both. The problem I have is I don't want to modify the table because obviously the table contains all possible groups. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would do all the work on the database side. Data source for first one is:

```
Select g.*
From membership m
  inner join groups g on m.groupid=g.groupid
Where m.userid = @userid
```

Data source for the second one looks like

```
Select g.*
From groups g
Where not exists 
  (Select 1 from membership m 
  Where m.GroupID=g.GroupID and m.userid = @userid
```

Then your add button inserts the appropriate row in the table and requeries both grids.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply make changes to the Dataset, then .AcceptChanges and re-bind. This would ensure the data would update on the screen without actually pushing it to the database.

Pseudo example:

```
Dim dt as Datatable = GetData1(strSQL.toString)
Dim dt2 as Datatable = GetData2(strSQL.toString)

Public Sub MoveRecord(ByVal dt1 as DataTable, ByVal dt2 as Datatable, ByVal index as Integer)

'Record being moved '
Dim dr as Datarow = dt.Rows(index)
dt2.Rows.Add(dr)
dt2.AcceptChanges
dt.Rows.RemoveAt(index)
dt.AcceptChanges

'Bind Gridview
 Perhaps store new changes in Viewstate,
 Cache, or Session for Paging, Sorting'
End Sub
```

Of course, this assumes the grids have the same fields. If they don't, you'd have to:

```
Dim drN as DataRow - dt2.Rows.NewRow
'Assign rows from moving datarow to new datarow'
dt2.Rows.Add(drN)
dt2.AcceptChanges
```